# This site can’t be reached error for Send attachments with e-mail using JSP, Servlet and JavaMail

Tags: java, jsp, email, servlets, jakarta-mail

I tried the example below. This is to Send attachments with e-mail using JSP, Servlet and JavaMail. I get This site can’t be reached error. May I know what changes are required to run this example correctly. You can directly download the war and project files from the links provided in the bottom of the page.

http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/jsp/send-attachments-with-e-mail-using-jsp-servlet-and-javamail#Download

Thanks in advance

Comment: It sounds like you can't connect to the server.  Try the [connection debugging tips in the JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).

Comment: Now I get error  Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;

Comment: And... What happened when you tried the connection debugging tips?